# How to decode QR Code version from image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, qr-code

I want to get the QR Code details, like version, error correction level, and mask.

I used OpenCV QR Code scanner, pyzbar, and zxing(python version), but I didn't see any API providing those methods.

For example:

I want to decode this QR Code and then get the QR Code details, how should I do?
[image]

Comment: So do you want to build a solution which takes QR codes as an input or are you attempting to inspect/debug the data stored in this specific QR code?

Comment: QR codes as an input image and output the details

Comment: Are the QR codes similar to the one you have depicted? You're going to probably need two steps for that one. Since the QR code does not occupy the entire image with 1 square being a pixel, it may have difficulty reading it. You could use a library which picks out a QR code from an image or you will need to manually remove the border and correct the image.

Comment: Have you used any libraries(opencv, pyzbar,and zxing)?  
I just want to get details from api  
In opencv I can get data like this  
qrDecoder = cv2.QRCodeDetector()  
data,bbox,rectifiedImage = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(inputImage)

Comment: For the extra challenge, you just need to identify how many squares you have (ex: 21x21), then read each dot as b or w. From here, [follow these steps](http://blog.qartis.com/decoding-small-qr-codes-by-hand/)